# How to put fixed-height shading around text (inline)?

Tags: color, boxes, height

I have a chunk of code in an alltt environment and I want to highlight elements that are auto-generated (two colours for different methods):

```
\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\colorbox{DGray}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tpl}[1]{\colorbox{Gray}{#1}}

\begin{alltt}
\gen{class }\tpl{Something}...
\end{alltt}
```

My problem is that the frame around 'Something' is taller than the one around 'class ' and reaches lower due to the letter 'g', so the two frames aren't aligned. Is there a way to make a shading frame with a fixed height and position? Basically, I want shading the OpenOffice/MS Office way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\strut`:

```
\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\colorbox{DGray}{\strut #1}}
\newcommand{\tpl}[1]{\colorbox{Gray}{\strut #1}}
```

or a `\vphantom` with some appropriate letters:

```
\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\colorbox{DGray}{\vphantom{Ag}#1}}
\newcommand{\tpl}[1]{\colorbox{Gray}{\vphantom{Ag}#1}}
```

or, to have even finer control, a `\rule` with the desired height and depth, and zero width:

```
\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\colorbox{DGray}{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{16pt}#1}}
\newcommand{\tpl}[1]{\colorbox{Gray}{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{16pt}#1}}
```